# currentColor set as a custom property doesn't work in Edge

Tags: css, microsoft-edge, custom-properties

When a `color` is set to `currentColor` via custom property it doesn't work.

No matter whether property is set in a `:root` or a `.selector` scope.

But when it is set as a `currentColor` directly it does work.

I checked it locally and on Browserstack. **Edge** ver. 17, 16

```
:root {
  --btn-content--color: currentColor;
}
.btn {
  color: red;
}
.btn-content {
  color: var(--btn-content--color); // doesn't work
}
.btn-content {
  color: currentColor; // works
}
```

You can try it yourself here: https://jsfiddle.net/9gmbfwu4/

Comment: According to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=currentColor), Edge fully supports the `currentColor` keyword, as well as CSS variables.

Comment: currentColor is supported, but CSS vars are not.

Comment: all other custom properties in Edge that we have do work, just this one doesn't `--btn-content--color: currentColor;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it ;]

```
:root {
  --btn-content--color: 'currentColor';
}
.btn {
  color: red;
}
.btn-content {
  color: var(--btn-content--color); // works as expected
}
```

Comment: From your last post I can see that you had solved the issue and posted your solution. I suggest you to mark that solution as an accepted answer for this question may help other community members in future. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT yeah, I just did. Anyway would be cool if someone knows why it behaves like that.

Comment: @ Luka, I will try to find an information about it, If any useful information is available for this topic then I will try to provide you.